# How to do transpose for tptrs in blas?

Tags: c, matrix, fortran, blas

How to do transpose for tptrs in blas?

I want to solve:

```
XA = B
```

But it seems that tptrs only lets me solve:

```
AX = B
```

Or, using the 'transpose' flag, in tptrs:

```
A'X = B
```

which, rearranging is:

```
(A'X)' = B'
X'A = B'
```

So, I can use it to solve XA = B, but I have to first transpose B manually myself, and then, again, transpose the answer.  Am I missing some trick to avoid having to do the transpose?

Comment: What are the dimensions of A, B, and X?

Comment: Undefined.  A is a square lower-triangular matrix.  B and X are both rectangular matrices.  All are dense (of course, since it's blas).  In general, A will be relatively small, whereas B and X will be long and thin.

Comment: I would not call it a 'trick,' but you *could* write your own matrix solver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TPTRS isn't a BLAS routine; it's an LAPACK routine.

If A is relatively small compared to B and X, then a good option to unpack it into a "normal" triangular matrix and use the BLAS routine TRSM which takes a "side" argument allowing you to specify XA = B. If A is mxm and B is nxm, the unpacking adds m^2 operations which will be a small amount of overhead compared to the O(nm^2) operations to do the solve.

Comment: Yes, I learned about TRSM a few days ago, and it's exactly the solution I was looking for, so I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: @HughPerkins: If your source A really is in packed form, note that you don't need to instantiate the complete unpacked form to use TRSM.  If you want to avoid doing that, you can choose a modest tile size (say 64x64) and unpack each tile and then call TRSM for the diagonal tiles and GEMM for the off-diagonal tiles.  Probably not something you need to worry about, however.

Comment: It isn't in packed form; just I didn't initially find TSRM, and the only function I found, initially, required packed form, which I then spent effort in obtaining from my original, unpacked, form ;-)